# How to output unicode box drawing in C++?

Tags: c++, unicode, visual-studio-2017

Sorry for what may sound simple, but I am trying to draw just a simple box in Visual Studio 2017 using the unicode characters from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character using the code below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓" << endl;
cout << "┃" << endl;
```

and so on...

However, whenever I run it all of the above code simply outputs as a ? wherever there should be a line.

So is it possible to output code like this directly to the console or for each character do I have to write the numeric values for each character?

Comment: Whatever you output to has to know the encoding and have the character set.

Comment: You must appreciate that the character set and encoding used when you write your code, is not the same as the character set and encoding being used when you run your program.

Comment: Your terminal window does not support the characters you want to print. This code works on my Gnome-terminal on my fedora 29. I don't know how to do that in Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows console apps can output wide strings (`L"..."`) directly to the terminal if the mode is set correctly. Note the use of `wcout` as well.  Save the following source in UTF-8 encoding:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wcout << L"┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓" << endl;
    wcout << L"┃" << endl;
}
```

Compile with "cl /EHsc /utf-8 test.cpp".  Output is:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃
```

Comment: `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` unfortunately it works only for the MS VC++, this is CRT specific undocumented trick.

Comment: @Victor Not undocumented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 2):

Windows console supports UTF-16LE UNICODE.

You can use some box-driving library like [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.sourceforge.io/) for example.

Otherwise you can use the following approach

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cwchar>

class output_swap {
    output_swap(const output_swap&) = delete;
    output_swap operator=(output_swap&) = delete;
public:
    output_swap( ) noexcept:
        prevCP_( ::GetConsoleCP() )
    {
        ::SetConsoleCP( CP_WINUNICODE );
        ::SetConsoleOutputCP( CP_WINUNICODE );
    }
    ~output_swap() noexcept {
        ::SetConsoleCP( prevCP_ );
        ::SetConsoleOutputCP( prevCP_ );
    }
private:
    ::DWORD prevCP_;
};

void draw_text(const wchar_t* text)
{
  static ::HANDLE _out = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  ::DWORD written;
  ::WriteConsoleW( _out, text, std::wcslen(text), &written, nullptr );
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
   output_swap swap;
   draw_text(L"┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓\n");
   draw_text(L"┃        OK       ┃\n");
   draw_text(L"┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Also check you console [font](https://www.wikihow.com/Customize-the-Font-in-Windows-Command-Prompt), in the console settings. You are probably need a raster font, but this is also working for Consolas for example.

If you need console io streams, which can work with unicode as well as box driwing you can use [my library](https://github.com/incoder1/IO/blob/master/examples/iostreams/main.cpp)