# How to use raw string literal in C++ VS (encoding problem)

Tags: c++, string, literals

I have English version of Win10 & English version of MSVS 2019 as well. When I used Russian versions, constructions like `cout << R"(Привет, мир!)" << endl;` worked fine (I could see text in my native language). As a variant, I was able to use `setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");` expression, and it worked too.
In English versions, nither first, nor second expression does not help. I see ????????? in place of expected text.
Tricks like `cout << u8R"(Привет, мир!)" << endl;` don`t help too. And more, when I save or compile project, VS asks me to make a choice abolut encoding, what to save the page. I tried to choose some at random (UTF, 1251, 1252...) but not succeeded.
How can I solve the problem?
P.S. In online compilers (like https://www.jdoodle.com/online-compiler-c++), the problem does not persist!

Comment: Is this about displaying text in console? If yes, then this is not C++ issue, but rather Windows setup issue. I'm not sure if it possible to set UTF-8 as encoding of Windows console and if not, then answer is: you can't do this at all. (You can setup Russian language as default even in English Windows, but I'm not sure if this is what you want.)

Comment: Also seems to me rather that the file editor (of VS) does not save the .cpp file as proper UTF. Maybe there is a setting where you can make sure its saved as UTF8?

Comment: This is Windows console functionality related issue. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302067/how-to-output-unicode-box-drawing-in-c/55302977#55302977). Also you can use my library for [UNICODE streams](https://github.com/incoder1/IO/blob/master/examples/iostreams/main.cpp)

Comment: Can you store the string in a variable `s` and check the values of `(int)s[i]`? If these values are the same for both english and russian Visual Studio, then the problem is not Visual Studio, but the console.

Answer (score 0):

I've understood, that problem is not with string compile or runtime error, but simply in console localization.
CHCP 65001 in console solves the problem.

```
cout << u8R"(Порядок. Спасибо)";
```