# Printing special characters on CMD from Compiled C++ Program (Windows 10)

Tags: c++

Hello guys I am working on a basic program with C++ this is a beginners project. I am trying to make a calculator with a nice looking prompt: This is what I want it to output:

```
┌──(C-Calc)
└─$
```

This is the code:

```
cout << "\033[1;32m ┌──(\033[36mC-Calc\033[1;32m)\n";
cout << "\033[1;32m └─$\033[1;37m ";
```

But this is the output instead:

```
ΓöîΓöÇΓöÇ(C-Calc)
ΓööΓöÇ$
```

I use the Microsoft Compiler `cl`

I Appreciate any support I can get here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to output unicode box drawing in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302067/how-to-output-unicode-box-drawing-in-c)

Comment: @GSerg I have tried the answer but I get different set of characters that are not what I am looking for.

Here they are:

â”Œâ”€â”€(C-Calc)
 â””â”€$

Comment: All the answers and comments are good on that potential duplicate. There is information listed there to consider that you need to include here.